# How to perform joins on non-primary columns and complex select statements in loopback 4?

Tags: node.js, express, rest, backend, loopback4

I am new to loopback and need to create an API with business logic that contains several complex queries. I can't seem to find a way to join two tables with non-primary columns. For example,

```
select * from e_c left join e on e.ed=e_c.ed where e.ed=1
```

Table relations:

- e_c.ed fk to ed table on id
- e.ed fk to ed table on id

On the same note writing complex select statements are also needed. For example,

```
select (case when completed_on is null then 1 else 0 end) flag from e
```

or

```
select sum(rating) from f_b
```

How these can be achieved via loopback 4?